# How to detect in my app device is currently connected to vehicle Carplay

Tags: ios, iphone, usb, eaaccessory, carplay

I googled lot but i did not get any hint. I want callback in my app when device is connect to carplay using cable.

I tried EAAccessory framework **(EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification
 and EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification)** for detection. But i can't differentiate device used for carplay or USB(charging purpose), I am getting callback for both event.

Please give me any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 12, if you're working on a CarPlay navigation app, you can utilize methods of `CPApplicationDelegate`. CarPlay audio apps are not provided with such facilities.